# How to restore a directory overwritten with mv?

Tags: ubuntu, files, directory, data-recovery, mv

I was planning to move a directory into another. The intended command is

```
mv evaluateA2P/ action2pose_bk/evaluateA2P/
```

However, I had a typo and executed

```
mv evaluateA2P/ action2pose_bk/ evaluateA2P/
```

Now, without a warning or prompt, the content of `action2pose_bk/` is overwritten with that of `evaluateA2P/`. Can I somehow restore the content, or I'd better hire a lawyer?

System information

```
Linux XXXXXXX-workstation3 5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 06:14:09 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is a demo of what just happened:

```
/tmp$ mkdir test1 test2
/tmp$ touch test2/important_file
/tmp$ mv test1 test2 test1
mv: cannot move 'test1' to a subdirectory of itself, 'test1/test1'
/tmp$ ls test2
ls: cannot access 'test2': No such file or directory
```

Comment: The command you posted that you said overwrote the contents of `action2pose_bk` would have actually errored and did nothing because you can't move a directory into itself. Some other command is responsible for your issue.

Comment: It's not clear what you are saying the result is. That command should have resulted in `action2pose_bk` being moved into `evaluateA2P`. To undo that you just need to do: `mv action2pose_bk/evaluateA2P  .`

Comment: @kaylum no, it should have resulted in `mv: cannot move 'evaluateA2P/' to a subdirectory of itself, 'evaluateA2P/evaluateA2P'`

Comment: @jordanm Yes but that's only for the first src arg. It will not abort the whole command and will still move the second src arg into the final dest.

Comment: As I said, just do: `mv test1/test2 .`

Comment: @kaylum Oh thank you. It works! I saw `test2` is gone and somehow convinced myself that it was overwrote by `test1`.

Comment: -1 for threatening to set your lawyer on me. I have never met you, now **** off (and what I did not say, is not as rude as setting a lawyer on someone).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor You certainly have the privilege to downvote, but I'm not threatening to set a lawyer on you! I was saying if there is no way I can restore the data, then I'd better find a lawyer in case my employer is going to sue me for the damages I have caused.

Comment: OK. You should explain that. But actually don't. I am not a lawyer, but I am pretty sure that your employer can use what you say against you. Do not admit any evidence.

Answer (score 1):

```
mv evaluateA2P/ action2pose_bk/ evaluateA2P/
```

The result of that command would be to move the `action2pose_bk` directory into the `evaluateA2P` directory. To undo that, simply move it back by running:

```
mv action2pose_bk/evaluateA2P .
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
mv test1/test2 . && mv test1 test2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like in your demonstration, here is what I get when I try your real scenario:

```
mv evaluateA2P/ action2pose_bk/ evaluateA2P/
mv: cannot move 'evaluateA2P/' to a subdirectory of itself, 'evaluateA2P/evaluateA2P'
```

Your command has not run to completion successfully. What it has done is move `action2pose_bk` into `evaluateA2P`, so simply move it back again

```
mv evaluateA2P/action2pose_bk .
```

Or, with your demo,

```
mv test1/test2 .
```

At this point you can try your intended command once more. Note, however, that it will succeed only if the target `action2post_bk/evaluateA2P` directory is either empty or does not yet exist:

```
mv evaluateA2P/ action2pose_bk/evaluateA2P/
```